# how to fix light on reflective surface

Tags: light, lighting, error

I rendered this musketeer sword and as you can see the light on the blade looks wrong and doesn't represent the actual shape.

so this is the solid view model with the blade in edit mode:

[image: solid view model]

and this is the rendered version (please ignore the awful materials):
[image]

In case someone need it, this is the blender file : [sword.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49724)

Comment: in what way does it not represent the actual shape? it looks correct

Comment: if you look above the triangular shape on the blade the light makes it look like two different pieces glued to each other.  dunno if that make sense

Comment: oh ok, it's because your plane is a little bit twisted (i.e. not really flat), you should rebuilt your mesh with a clean mesh structure (quads and edge loops). If you want to let it like it is you can quickly fix the problem with a trick: select the mesh and click on Properties > Data > Normals > Auto Smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh ok, it's because your plane is a little bit twisted (i.e. not really flat), you should rebuilt your mesh with a clean mesh structure (quads and edge loops). If you want to let it like it is you can quickly fix the problem with a trick: select the mesh and click on Properties > Data > Normals > Auto Smooth